# What CSS Selector to use to remove property from nested class?

Tags: html, css

```css
 .row {
      padding-left: 15px;
      padding-right: 15px;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="row">
       <div class="col"> </div>
       <div class="col"> </div>
       <div class="col row">
           <div class="col"> </div>
           <div class="col"> </div>
       </div>
    </div>
```

What I need:

- To remove the paddings on ALL nested and deeply row class
- `.row > .row` would not suffice since it only affects one layer deep

Comment: use `.row  .row`

Comment: Then remove the `>` which makes it only one layer deep. `.row .row`

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `.row, .row .row`

```css
.row {
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  min-height: 10px;
}

.row,
.row .row {
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
   <div class="col"> </div>
   <div class="col"> </div>
   <div class="col row">
       <div class="col"> </div>
       <div class="col"> </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This would remove padding from all `.row` regardless of depth. Just the `.row .row` will do.